# gnuplot - eps with a large number of points

Tags: png, gnuplot, heatmap, resolution

I have a datafile with many columns, data are not arranged in a grid, and would like to plot heat maps.
My problem is that the number of points is very large, and since there is no structures grid, I do not know how to treat it without producing humongous files.

I unsuccessfully tried to turn it into a grid via `dgrid3d` and then `splot` it, or to `p ... with image` it, while plotting it into a png picture poses me the problem of consistently set the size of the picture, as well as the scale of the font, with the rest of the document.

How do you usually solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you are working in a LaTeX environment, one solution is to use `set term cairolatex png`. This gives you integrated text handling via latex and the guaranteed size limit on the graphics component because it is produced as a png image.